# Java Swing and ActionListeners

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I am still new to using Swing and creating GUIs in Java. I was working on a simple test code where the color of a button changes to a random color when it is pressed. Although it works, every time I press the button, it minimizes the previous window and opens a new one and they keep piling up. How will I make it so that this does not happen? Does this occur because I am creating an object in the actionPerformed method? The reason why I have made an object there is to link the Swing class with the separate Action class I have made in order to manipulate the button variable.

Therefore, my two questions are:

- How can I prevent multiple windows from appearing and instead have them replace each other?
- Is there a way to utilize ActionListener within the same class and would it make things easier?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;




public class Swing extends JFrame{

    private JFrame f;
    private JLabel l;
    private JButton b;
    private JPanel p;



    public Swing(){
        test();
    }

    //*
    public JFrame getJFrame(){
        return f;
    }

    public JLabel getJLabel(){
        return l;
    }

    public JButton getJButton(){
        return b;
    }

    public JPanel getJPanel(){
        return p;
    }
    //*


    public void test(){

    // Frame Setup
    f = new JFrame("Frame");
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setResizable(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //


    // Panel Setup
    p = new JPanel();
    p.setVisible(true);
    //

    // Other
    b = new JButton("Button");
    l = new JLabel("Label");
    b.addActionListener(new Action());

    //

    // Additions
    p.add(b);
    p.add(l);
    f.add(p); // ***
    //

}







    public static void main(String[] args){

    Swing swing = new Swing();
    swing.test();




}
}

final class Action implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Swing swingObject = new Swing(); // 

        JButton button = swingObject.getJButton(); // 
        button.setBackground(randomColor());

        }




public Color randomColor(){

    Random rn = new Random();
    ArrayList<Color> color = new ArrayList<Color>();
    color.add(Color.BLUE);
    color.add(Color.GREEN);
    color.add(Color.RED);
    color.add(Color.YELLOW);
    color.add(Color.PINK);
    color.add(Color.CYAN);
    color.add(Color.ORANGE);
    color.add(Color.MAGENTA);


    int s = color.size();
    int random = rn.nextInt(s);

    return color.get(random);

}
}
```

Comment: You should try to focus on having one question per post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your listener, you're executing

```
Swing swingObject = new Swing();
```

This does what it should do: create a new Swing JFrame. You don't want a new JFrame, so don't call its constructor. From the listener, simply get the button that fired the event, and change its color:

```
JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
button.setBackground(randomColor());
```

You could also pass the button to modify when creating the listener:

```
class Action implements ActionListener{
    private JButton buttonToUpdate;

    public Action(JButton buttonToUpdate) { 
        this.buttonToUpdate = buttonToUpdate;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        buttonToUpdate.setBackground(randomColor());
    }
}
```

And, to create it:

```
b = new JButton("Button");
b.addActionListener(new Action(b));
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much I had a feeling that the object was the reason for the numerous windows but I did not know a good way around it and you showed me two good ways and I went with the second way and added a constructor to the Action class. Thank you very much :)